# How to get User profile data by their username stored in Firebase Firestore without logging in? Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have a flutter project in which every user create their profile and store some data in it by using firebase firestore.
I want to know that how a user can access or see the profile data of other users by their usernames without logging in?

For example: Facebook profile of anyone by *facebook.com/username*. anyone can see the profile of the user without logging in.

Comment: If you've stored the information in Firestore, you should be able to [read all documents](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_all_documents_in_a_collection) from that collection. Is tht not working for you?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to control the access to documents and collections in your database I suggest that you use and modify the security rules. In this case what you want is to allow read access only for specific fields (user profile). This [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-fields) show you how control access to specific fields.